# Undefined variables in class

Tags: php, class, variables, undefined

I'm using a raspberry pi to control lightning in my apartment, and currently I'm writing a class to control RGB Leds. However, I'm having some troubles with it, and this particular problem is going to drive me crazy.

Whenever I call a function, setRed() for example, I get a notice that says `Notice: Undefined variable: GPIORed in M:\wamp\www\LedControl\class.rgbcontrol.php on line 16`

Shortened version of my class looks like this:

```
class RGBControl {

    var $GPIORed;
    var $GPIOGreen;
    var $GPIOBlue;

    public function __construct($red,$green,$blue) {
      $this->GPIORed = $red;
      $this->GPIOGreen = $green;
      $this->GPIOBlue = $blue;
    }


    public function setRed($power){
        shell_exec("echo \"$GPIORed=$power\" > /dev/pi-blaster");
    }

    public function setGreen($power){
        shell_exec("echo \"$GPIOGreen=$power\" > /dev/pi-blaster");
    }

    public function setBlue($power){
        shell_exec("echo \"$GPIOBlue=$power\" > /dev/pi-blaster");
    }
}
```

So here's basic usage, I'm defining the class with arguments 24,23,18 (the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi that my leds are connected to).

```
$LED = new RGBControl (24,23,18);

$LED->setRed($color[0] / 255);
$LED->setGreen($color[1] / 255);
$LED->setBlue($color[2] / 255);
```

But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the array `$color` coming from?

Comment: @girlwithglasses doesn't matter - it's not part of the direct issue...

Comment: I'd set visibility on the three `var`'s, too. (Not part of the answer, though)

Comment: @hd. Could you explain what you mean with visibility?

Comment: For example, `public $var`, `private $var`, `protected $var`. See http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @hd. Doesn't `var` do the same thing? According to the manual it does. `If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines like this:

```
shell_exec("echo \"$GPIOBlue=$power\" > /dev/pi-blaster");
```

are trying to resolve variables named `$GPIOBlue` and `$power`, but `$GPIOBlue` doesn't exist. You need to use `$this` to access instance member variables. For example,

```
shell_exec("echo \"{$this->GPIOBlue}=$power\" > /dev/pi-blaster");
```

Comment: Of course. I did read a few questions about similar problems and they all solved the problem with $this->Variable but I was unable to connect the dots... I was having problems inside the class itself and others were trying to access the variables outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function setRed($power){
    shell_exec("echo \"$GPIORed=$power\" > /dev/pi-blaster");
}
```

<s>You are trying to access the $GPIORed variable in the scope of the shell interpreter. It is only accessible through php.</s> *Like Dan mentioned, it's a scope reference issue. My bad.*

I would recommend using a file operation instead of using shell_exec, partly because of security and partly because of readability.

```
file_put_contents("/dev/pi-blaster", "{$this->GPIORed}=$power\n");
```

Comment: I'm not really trying to access in the scope of the shell interpreter, as I assumed that php will replace the $GPIORed with 24 as it does with $power. I'll consider the file_put_contents but I'll have to run a few speed tests first :)

Comment: `file_put_contents` is definitely a better approach than `shell_exec`, regardless of performance (although, I'd be shocked if it were slower). Too many things can go wrong with `shell_exec`.

Comment: My mistake, it was more of a theory. I've always been wary of shell executions. I would add a check for integer values before writing them to /dev/pi-blaster just to be safe. :)

Comment: @NuclearPeon Yeah I'm doing that but I simplified the class before posting as I knew that it's not the problem :)

Comment: @Dan Guess what, you don't need to be shocked. I ran some tests with microtime() and the result for file_put_contents is `Time: 0.0003 Seconds` and for shell_exec `Time: 0.0132 Seconds`. So it's only a **few** times faster ;) But shell_exec wasn't really that slow, so I got that going for me, which is nice.